# Factor base for RSA cryptosystem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, prime-factorization, cryptography

In RSA crptosystem, we choose two big primes $p,q$ and set $n=pq$. $n$ is public and roughly, the aim is factorize $n$ to decrypt the encrpyted message.

A method to attack the system is the following:

> **Basic Principle**. Let $n$ be an integer and suppose that there exist integers $x,y$ with $x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod n$ but $x \not \equiv \pm y \pmod n$. Then, $n$ is composite. Moreover, $gcd(x-y,n)$ gives a nontrivial factor of $n$.

Thus, we look for an equivalence as above.

Now, my question on "*factor base*", a set of prime numbers. Let $n$ be given and we want to factorize it. We choose a set of prime numbers which we call as factor base $B$. We pick random numbers $a$ and write $a^2 \equiv p_1^2 p_2p_5 \pmod n$ so that the prime factors only belong to the base $B$. Then, we factorize $(a+1)^2,(a+2)^2 \dots etc.$ modulo $n$ so that the prime factors are contained in $B$. We multiply the elements on the left and right so that the process stops when we have squares on the boths sides, an equivalence like $$a^2 (a+2)^2 (a+3)^2 \equiv p_2^4 p_3^2 p_6^4 \pmod n$$

Thus, we find $x^2 \equiv y^2 \pmod n$ provided that $x \not \equiv \pm y \pmod n$.

This is how I understand the method but I do not have any idea on the following questions:

Let Alice and Bob use RSA for their communication and let $\{p_1, . . . , p_{20} \}$ be a set of primes to use for key construction.

1.How to find the number of secure RSA keys?

2.If both  selects their primes randomly how to find the probability that the keys not secure?

Comment: What do you mean by *secure* in the phrase, "secure RSA keys"? What would it take for a key not to be secure?

Comment: I am not sure, the book I follow is not so educative. I guess that if you find  the number $x$ quickly then it is not secure. Also, somehow, if the base $B$ contains 'small primes' then the book says it is not secure. I do not know and cannot see the reason of that.

Comment: Well, then, the first thing to do is to find out what the book means by "secure". If you don't even understand the question, how do you expect anyone to give you an answer?

Comment: There are only 210 pairs in total(assuming pairs that are factors of n are what you are looking for  otherwise 1048575 are possible.). Also, if you have the right keys no factorization is needed, but factorization can help break it if you don't have these.